# Do we get such an $f\ $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, continuity, approximation

> Does there exist any $f \in C[0,\pi]$ such that $\dfrac {\left \lvert \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \sin^2 x\ dx \right \rvert} {\sup\limits_{x \in [0,\pi]} |f(x)|} = \frac {\sqrt 3 \pi} {2 \sqrt 2} \ ?$ By Holder's inequality I find that for any $f \in C[0,\pi]$ we have $\dfrac {\left \lvert \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \sin^2 x\ dx \right \rvert} {\sup\limits_{x \in [0,\pi]} |f(x)|} \leq \frac {\sqrt 3 \pi} {2 \sqrt 2}.$ Can this bound be attained?

Comment: Constant function?

Comment: @Seewoo Lee No for constant functions this bound would be $\frac {\pi} {2}.$

Comment: Oh ok the question is just changed :)

Comment: I mean, if Holder bounds that quantity by a number smaller than $\pi$, what's the point of asking if that quantity can be $\pi$?

Comment: @Gae. S look at my last question.

Comment: @Phibetakappa I did, but why did I have to read another question before, which you already claim having provably negative answer? If anything, illustrating how you came by that bound is a better usage of that space.

Comment: @Gae.S. edited the question.